# To include a file from another Directory?

Tags: c, linux

I know the path of a file which is in another directory. How can I be able to access the file's functions from another directory?

> Compiler : gcc compiler
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
> Release:        20.04
> Codename:       focal
> Kernel : 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Comment: You can use full paths (both relative and absolute) in your `#include` directives. Like `#include "path/to/some/file.h"`

Comment: ... but you probably should not, because of different path-syntaxes. Better prefer to configure the include search folders for building.

Comment: With that said, header files that you `#include` typically only have function *declarations*. The function *definitions* (the implementation) usually is in another source file that you need to explicitly build with.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], with multiple files as separate code quotes, with file name and path specified. You might be mistaken about how far including something might get you. Also include-trees are tetchy if you do not follow the rules. And maybe linking  to libs or adding more code files to your project comes into the picture.

Comment: @Yunnosch Especially the backslash path separator is not a permitted character, AFAIK. Anyway, the matching to paths is implementation defined.

Comment: @thebusybee I might be missing your point. I think you are supporting my comment on avoiding paths in include statements.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yeah, sorry. The backslash is sometimes used by beginners on Windows. -- I'm mostly supporting your statement, on the other hand it is quite common to include one or two levels of directories like `#include <sys/bits.h>`. All the instances I saw in 40+ years use the forward slash as path separator. But you're right to avoid full paths at all.

Comment: @thebusybee OK, thanks for clarifying. The bits are an exceptionally gruesome example for that practice in my opinion. Still a valid example.

Answer (score 1):

2 different ways to accomplish this

1: pass `-I./dirName` to the compiler and add `#include <filename.h>` to the source file. -I means to include a directory that will reference .h files, and <> in C is used to indicate that we want to grab from an included directory.

2: Add `#include "../filename.h"` to the source code to include a header file from another directory.